# PySpark RDD processing for sum of parts

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a RDD with tuples like (datetime, integer).
And I try to get another RDD of some interval summation with pyspark.

For example, from followings

```
(2015-09-30 10:00:01, 3)
(2015-09-30 10:00:02, 1)
(2015-09-30 10:00:05, 2)
(2015-09-30 10:00:06, 7)
(2015-09-30 10:00:07, 3)
(2015-09-30 10:00:10, 5)
```

I'm trying to get followings sum of every 3 seconds:

```
(2015-09-30 10:00:01, 4)  # sum of 1, 2, 3 seconds
(2015-09-30 10:00:02, 1)  # sum of 2, 3, 4 seconds
(2015-09-30 10:00:05, 12) # sum of 5, 6, 7 seconds
(2015-09-30 10:00:06, 10) # sum of 6, 7, 8 seconds
(2015-09-30 10:00:07, 3)  # sum of 7, 8, 9 seconds
(2015-09-30 10:00:10, 5)  # sum of 10, 11, 12 seconds
```

Please, could you give me any hints?

Comment: So you want a sliding window, where the window is the current second + the next two?

Comment: Yes, I want a kind of sliding window. But not just next N items, but next N seconds. Data is not consecutive in every seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume that your input is an RDD `time_rdd` with tuples where the first element is a datetime object and the second element is an integer. You could use a flatMap to map every datetime object to the previous 3 seconds and then use a reduceByKey to get the total count for that window.

```
def map_to_3_seconds(datetime_obj, count):
    list_times = []
    for i in range(-2, 1):
        list_times.append((datetime_obj + timedelta(seconds = i), count))
    return list_times

output_rdd = time_rdd.flatMap(lambda (datetime_obj, count): map_to_3_seconds(datetime_obj, count)).reduceByKey(lambda x,y: x+y)
```

This RDD will contain more datetime objects than the ones in the original RDD, so if you only want to have the original times, then you need to do a join with the `time_rdd`,

```
result = output_rdd.join(time_rdd).map(lambda (key, vals): (key, vals[0])).collect()
```

Now result will contain:

```
[(datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 30, 10, 0, 5), 12),
(datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 30, 10, 0, 2), 1),
(datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 30, 10, 0, 10), 5),
(datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 30, 10, 0, 1), 4),
(datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 30, 10, 0, 6), 10),
(datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 30, 10, 0, 7), 3)]
```